# Regex expression to match string not containing other two substrings

Tags: regex

So,

I need a regex expression to match a string that does not include a couple of substrings. I want regex to match all lines containing `/paths` in them unless they contain `string1` or `string2` prior to `/paths`

Do not match:
`foo = string1("/paths`
`string2 + "/paths`
`string1 = "/paths`
`"#{string2}/paths`

But matches:
`source("/paths`
`bg : "/paths`

Thanks

Comment: Obviously the right answer is `grep /paths | grep -v 'string[12].*/paths'`.

Comment: @tchrist thank you if you could add it as an answer so I could pick it up as the right answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following sed command to do so
`sed -i -e '/string1\|string2/!s/paths/fix_paths/gI' FILE_NAME`

It does not do exactly search for the strings prior my paths, but it matched what I intended to match and worked for my specific case.

Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in particular the section on positive and negative look-behinds.

something similar to (this is untested) this:

`(?<!*?string1*?|*?string2*?)"/paths"`

Answer (score 1):

If you use a flavor that supports lookaheads, this will work:

```
^(?:(?!string1|string2|/paths).)*/paths
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to go around another way to do this with and if/else, ie  check for string1 or string2 in your string, if its found, then don't process.

```
if "string1" in string or "string2" in string then
  ...
else
  process
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

You one grep for what you want and another with `-v` for what you don't what:

```
$ grep want_string input_file | grep -v unwant_string
```